# verify multiline alert webdriver

Tags: webdriver, multiline, alerts

I need to verify the text in a multiline alert but I really cannot make it work.

The alert is like:

```
- Please enter firstname:
- Please enter lastname:
- ..............................
```

And I use:

```
verifyEquals("Verify msg",
        ObjectHelp.closeAlertAndGetItsText(true),
        "Please enter firstname:Please enter lastname:");
```

But it gives me FALSE for some reason!

I tried to debug and the alert text is really "Please enter firstname:Please enter lastname:" so, no doubts on that.

How can I manage multiline alerts?

Answer (score 1):

I *bet* the actual text of the alert is *not* `"Please enter firstname:Please enter lastname:"`.

It's more likely `"Please enter firstname:\nPlease enter lastname:"` (notice the `\n`).

You should confirm this in the page source, or the JS file containing the call.

Anyway, the right thing to assert here is

```
verifyEquals("Verify msg",
        ObjectHelp.closeAlertAndGetItsText(true),
        "Please enter firstname:\nPlease enter lastname:");
```

Comment: great, the \n was missing :-)